# The numbers of references didn' t appear in beamer? How to solve?

Tags: beamer, bibtex

[image]

The numbers of references didn' t appear in beamer? How to solve?

Comment: Beamer's bibitems are designed to output no numbers if not requested by the user or the template.

Comment: If the linked question does not solve your problem, please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Just posting screenshots without any code to reproduce your problems is really not the best way to ask for help